# How to transfer some builtin methods to a class variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, inheritance

I have class in which I want to implement list-like or dict-like behavior through a class variable.

```
class Property(list):
    def __init__(self, data: list = None, name: str):
        self.data = data or []
        self.name = name

prop = Property([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], 'property')
print(prop[1])  # 2
print(prop[:3])  # [1, 2, 3]
print(prop.name)  # 'property'
```

I want Property when it is called with some list methods, like append(), pop(), index() to work with self.data variable as list.

```
class Node(dict):
    def __init__(self, data: dict = None):
        self.data = data or {}
        self.order = []
        for x in data:
            # do stuff to fill data & order

node = Node({'a': '1', 'b': '2', 'c': '3'})
print(node.keys())  # ['a', 'b', 'c']
print('c' in node)  # True
print(node['b'])  # '2'
print(node.order)  # some ordered list
```

Same here, I want it to work directly with self.data variable with dict-like methods.

Is there a way to do so with something like `super().__init__()`?

Comment: In that case, you may not want an `__init__` method in your subclass...

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, I have edited the examples ^_^

Comment: You must decide whether you want Property to be a list subclass or have a list as an attribute.  Don't make it both.  If instances are a list, initialize self, not self.data.  If instances have a list as 'data', you must write the Property methods that call data methods yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the UserList and UserDict classes from the [collections](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html) module.  You can't get the behaviour you expect by inheriting directly from the builtin list and dict types because they're implemented in C (in CPython at least), so these classes were made for this purpose.

```
from collections import UserList, UserDict, OrderedDict

class Property(UserList):
    def __init__(self, data: list = None, name: str = None):
        self.data = data or []
        self.name = name

prop = Property([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], 'property')
print(prop[1])  # 2
print(prop[:3])  # [1, 2, 3]
print(prop.name)  # 'property'

class Node(UserDict):
    def __init__(self, data: dict = None):
        self.data = OrderedDict(data) if data else OrderedDict()

node = Node({'a': '1', 'b': '2', 'c': '3'})
print(node.keys())  # KeysView(OrderedDict([('a', '1'), ('b', '2'), ('c', '3')]))
print([c for c in node.keys()]) # ['a','b','c']
print('c' in node)  # True
print(node['b'])  # '2'
```

You need to do some more work on your dict class but I think you can figure that out.

It's also worth noting that you could use an [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) for Node data, which gives you the ordering you want.

Comment: "you can't really" is ambigous. Either you can or you can't. And you can, but you'll not be able to get the expected behaviour when overriding special methods.

Comment: Hence "you can't really", because as you say you can but you won't get any of the behaviour you want.

Comment: That's right, I am just suggesting you to be explicit in your answer, for those unaware of this, as might be the OP case.

Comment: @Turksarama thanks for the idea, I'll try to figure it out.

Comment: The fact that `list` is written in C doesn't stop classes from inheriting from it. There is no reason to use `UserList` or `UserDict` here.

Comment: Try it and see what happens

Comment: Do it [*properly*](https://ideone.com/kxjSnz), treating `self` as a list or dict instead of using a `self.data` attribute, and everything works fine. Your code only works because `UserDict` and `UserList` already use a `data` attribute for their underlying storage.

Comment: That isn't "properly", that's a (perfectly fine) way that you can do it if you don't need to do anything too complicated, but is harder to extend.  What is the benefit?  Does it run faster?

Comment: @Turksarama, well, I've managed to achive everything I need with Property(UserList) and Node(OrderedDict). Thank you!